# Retrieve Auto-Generated ID in Java Code From Oracle DataBase

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBC Template with Oracle Database.
I want to get back the auto-generated ID field upon successful DB insertion.

**Please help me to get the auto-generated ID from DB**

Here is my sample code:

```
public class EmployeeObject {   
    int employeeId;
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


}
```

**--DAO Interface--**

```
public interface CreateEmployeeDao {

    public void insertIntoEmployeeObject(EmployeeObject employeeObject);
}
```

**--DAO IMPL--**

```
public class CreateEmployeeDaoImpl implements CreateEmployeeDao{

    @Override
    public void insertIntoEmployeeObject(EmployeeObject employeeObject){
            String sqlInsertObject = CreateEmployeeDBQueryConstants.INSERT_OBJECT_DETAILS.toString();
            int record = getJdbcTemplate().update(sqlInsertObject,
                    new Object[] { employeeObject.getEmployeeId(),
                                   employeeObject.getFirstName(), 
                                   employeeObject.getLastName()});
    }

}
```

**DB QUERY CONSTRANT**

```
public class CreateEmployeeDBQueryConstants {       

    public static final StringBuffer INSERT_OBJECT_DETAILS = new StringBuffer(100);

        static{     
        INSERT_OBJECT_DETAILS.append("insert into EXPORT_OBJECT "
                + "(EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME,EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME, "
                + " values (?,?,?)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use overloaded version of `update` method that takes `PreparedStatementCreator` and `KeyGenerator` as arguments (documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-)):

Your code will look like this:

```
KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
PreparedStatementCreator creator = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement insertStatement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_OBJECT_DETAILS, new Object[] { 
                               employeeObject.getEmployeeId(),
                               employeeObject.getFirstName(), 
                               employeeObject.getLastName()}));
        return insertStatement;
    }
};
getJdbcTemplate().update(creator, holder);
System.out.println(holder.getKey());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`GeneratedKeyHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html) as @Darshan has mentioned is the way to go.

I prefer using the method as shown in http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/spring-jdbc-insert-auto-generated-key :

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sqlString, parameters, keyHolder);
return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
```